# Cross cutting narrow stock using a track saw

Tags: technique, circular-saw

I have (very) limited working space and I intend buying a track saw in order to do rip cuts, cross cuts, beveled cuts. I cannot fit a table saw unfortunately.

**I was wondering, can I cross cut 2x4s using the track saw using the aluminum track?**

Does it make sense? Can I sag the track as most of it would be unsupported? Should I clamp it to some sacrificial scrap wood, below the track, at its ends, in order to prevent the sagging? Should I take totally different route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use a track saw to cut 2x4s if it is able to cut that deep. What I have found very helpful is to get a sheet of foam insulation board (not white bead board) to use as your saw table this gives you a platform to cut on protecting the surface underneath (floor or benchtop). To cut 2x4s just prop up the other end of the track so you're not fighting with it trying to move on you as you cut. While most suited for sheet goods and flooring plunge cuts the track saw is a very versatile saw and easily replaces a table saw while saving lots of space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A small follow-up question, if I may: Is it reasonable to try to use the track (the track saw can be used without the track) for such short-length cuts? I was leaning towards using the track in order to ensure a very straight line, a thing that might not be achievable without the track, not even when using a speed-square or other improvised guide, as I thought.

Comment: There is (if the saw allows) no reason you can't use the saw without track. Sometimes the track defines the saw path much more clearly than just the base. Try both ways and see which works better for you.

Comment: If you're going to do a lot of crosscuts I'd suggest getting a track square and cutting a 3' track in half.  Or get an MFT-3.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly crosscut 2x stock with a track saw.  The depth of cut on the TS55 (and most competitors) is just over 2".

You'll probably want a few things to make the job easier, though.

You'll definitely want some way to support both your workpiece and the offcut.  This can be as simple as a sacrificial sheet of MDF or rigid insulation.

The MFT-3 comes with a fence and rigging to hold a track.  This will let you accurately cut 90-degree angles and support your workpiece.  You'll still need something to support longer offcuts, though.

There are also squares that you can attach to the track to allow you to set up more quickly than the MFT-3.  ([Here is an example.](https://tsoproducts.com/tso-products-guide-rail-squares/grs-16-guide-rail-square/))  You can couple this with a very small section of track (cut down from what Festool sells) to use specifically for crosscutting.

If you're mainly going to be working with 2x stock doing rough framing work I'd suggest looking at the HK55 as well.  It's a non-plunging track saw that's attached to the track.  It's specifically designed for crosscutting.